# Різниця між словами "просити" та "прохати"

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Чи критичною є різниця між словами *"просити"* та *"прохати"* у плані запиту на виконання якогось вчинку (наприклад, *"попрохати допомогти"* чи *"попросити допомогти"* (або ж і "допомоги"))?

Яке зі слів краще використовувати у тексті для надання йому більшої плавності? Так може здатися, що вони рівноцінні. Форум, наприклад, [остаточної](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=41602.0) відповіді, яка б задовольнила, не надав.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Різниці між *просити* і *прохати* немає, окрім значення *призначати ціну за що-небудь*, де коректно вживати *просити*.**

---

СУМ [стверджує](http://sum.in.ua/s/prokhaty), що це слова-синоніми:

> ПРОХАТИ, аю, аєш, недок., перех. і неперех. Те саме, що [просити](http://sum.in.ua/s/prosyty)
>   1, 2, 4, 5.

Єдине значення, де немає відповідності - це *призначати ціну за що-небудь*:

> 3). неперех., розм. Призначати ціну за що-небудь. *— Він просить по
>   тридцять карбованців за шкурку. Чи не взяти нам пару?* (Зінаїда Тулуб,
>   В степу.., 1964, 459); *— Завжди на ярмарку знайдеш двох дурнів: один
>   дорого просить, другий дешево дає* (Михайло Стельмах, Гуси-лебеді..,
>   1964, 81).

Я також припустив, що *прохати* може бути щось середнім між *просити* і *благати*, проте Вікісловник [не підтверджує](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BD.D1.96.D0.BC.D0.B8) цю гіпотезу:

> Благати - наполег­ливо, невідступно, ласкаво просити. *Сам і їсти їй
>   при­носить, І просить, благає, Щоб на його подивилась, Щоб утерла
>   очі...* Шевченко
>
> Синоніми: заклинати, молити, волати, упрошувати

Ще один ресурс [вказує](https://www.dictionaries24.com/uk/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), що *просити* і *прохати* є синонімами *благати*, а отже, теж ставить синомінімну відповідність цим словам.